# The meaning of けど

Tags: grammar, meaning

> お金があったら、車を買うんですけど。
>
> If I had money, I would buy a car.

I know that けど　means "but," "however" or "although".

Why is it used in the sentence above? How is the sentence different from the one below?

> お金があったら、車を買うんです。